# Can't catch the ForeColor command anymore, tinymce 4.1.4

Tags: javascript, wordpress, tinymce, tinymce-4

Tinymce used to fire an event for the text-color-change, if you ran:

```
tinymce.activeEditor.on('execCommand', function() {console.log(arguments);} )
```

you would see the execCommand ForeColor, ran whenever the text color is changed. If you look in TinyMCE-Textcolor plugin, it doesn't seem to have any execCommands or any way to detect when text-color changes.

Comment: The TextColor plugin no longer fires the execCommand event because [since this commit it](https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce/commit/2adfc8dc5467c4af77ff0e5403d00ae33298ed52) directly uses the [Formatter infrastructure](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/api4:class.tinymce.Formatter). So you cannot get your old event but you can use the `formatChanged` on the formatter to provide a callback: http://jsfiddle.net/9hb4zbyj/. However this will also fire even if you just select some text which is already colored... so sadly this is not the best alternative

Comment: @nemesv Since you can 'monkey-patch' editor.formatter.apply, your comment is basically the answer to this question - Why don't you make your comment the answer?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The TextColor plugin no longer fires the `execCommand` event because [since this commit](https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce/commit/2adfc8dc5467c4af77ff0e5403d00ae33298ed52) it directly uses the [Formatter infrastructure](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/api4:class.tinymce.Formatter). So you cannot get your old event.

However you can use the `formatChanged` on the formatter to provide a callback:

```
tinymce.activeEditor.formatter.formatChanged('forecolor', function (isNew, args) {
    if (isNew)
    console.log("new color", args.node.style.color);
}, true)
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9hb4zbyj).

But this will also fire even if you just select some text which is already colored... so sadly this is not the best alternative.

Of course the `formatter.apply` can be monkey-patched to fire the old `ExecCommand` event:

```
var oldApply = tinymce.activeEditor.formatter.apply;

tinymce.activeEditor.formatter.apply = function apply(name, vars, node) {
    oldApply(name, vars, node);
    tinymce.activeEditor.fire('ExecCommand', {name: name, vars: vars});
}
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eaookq1L/).

But this cannot be done globally and have to repeated for every tinymce editor instance so it is again not the best solution...

Comment: I added the formatter.apply monkey-patch to the init_instance_callback callback of tinymce.init. That let me apply this to each instance as it was created, instead of relying on tinymce.activeEditor.